# Using regex in cloud functions

Tags: javascript, regex, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to test a string that is from an input using a regular expression.
it is a quite simple regex: [0-9]{8}
The problem is that I keep getting an error.

The code:

```
  const GETparam = req.query.kvk;
  const KvK = GETparam.toString();

  //Test if it is a valid KvK number [0-9]{8}
  var KvKregex = new Regexp('[0-9]{8}');
  if(KvKregex.test(KvK) != true){
    res.status(405).send('KvK number provided was invalid');
    return;
  }
```

Explaination: If the input from the GET parameter(http://......?kvk=number), the kvk number, doesn't match the regex, it should return a 405. Else, the code should just keep running.
It says Regexp is not defined.

Do I need to include something? I can't find how to actually use a regular expression in a cloud function. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cloud Functions nodejs environment is just plain nodejs running JavaScript.  Cloud Functions don't not change the way the language works.

You should use **RegExp** (note the capital E) instead of Regexp.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp